# When to implement a CDI Event?

Tags: jsf, events, jakarta-ee, cdi

When a user clicks a button on JSF, a managed bean receives the input value from front end. To process the request and respond, when should or shouldn't I implement a CDI event? For instance, to print back "Hello World" to html page after a user clicks a button on a front end JSF page, I can implement a CDI Event using event-observer model, or I can do the same thing in many other ways.

My question is, what are appropriate scenarios to implement a request-process operation as a CDI event? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you want to use events when a request from user will affect multiple parts of application. Let's say user changed some settings it his profile and they are multiple components affected by this change so you can fire up an single event and all these components will be able to handle the configuration change.

Another argument for using events is to decouple your components so there are less dependencies in your application.

So for your example, events are probably overkill for such simple operation as printing Hello world.

Comment: What about to retrieve some records from a database and respond to the front request? As for "fire up an single event and all these components will be able to handle the configuration change.", can I use a single method to handle all components with changes?

Comment: An observer is usually implemented as an method, so that's not significantly different from a method that resides in a class?

Comment: Well, in CDI it's method with `@Observes` argument, so it's really not different from normal methods.

Comment: I am sorry, but could you clarify you first question? I am not sure what you are trying to achieve